# Seje e esteje ou seja e esteja?

Tags: ortografia, conjugações, modo-subjuntivo, ser-estar

Já ouvi o termo *"seje"* e *"esteje"*, no entanto me surgiu as duvidas

O correto é *"seja"* e *"esteja"* ou *"seje"* e *"esteje"*?

Answer (score 6):

As formas corretas são **seja** e **esteja**, embora "seje" e "esteje" sejam comuns na linguagem oral de determinados registros (tipos de grupos de falantes).

Comment: Se vocês vissem as pronuncias que temos em Portugal ficavam loucos, até para nós mesmos é de loucos. Há alguns sítios cá que não se percebe nada do que as pessoas dizem.